# How to determine the corner frequency needed?

Tags: filter, low-pass

I want to design a second order sallen key low pass filter.  I want to attenuate a 100Hz signal to around 10%.  I need to use a 2nd order low pass filter.  How could I calculate the corner frequency such that I will achieve this 10% attenuation at 100Hz?
In this case a Butterworth Filter has to be used.

Comment: A lowpass of 2nd order is determined not only by its corner frequency but also the form of the pass-band (maximally flat oder with a certain peaking). Hence, you have to select one of the corresponding approximations (Bessel or Butterworth or Chebyshev I or Chebyshev II ).

Comment: In this case a Butterworth filter is going to be used

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question on dsp.SE? I can't find it, did you delete it? There was a comment in there...

Answer (score 2):

Attenuating to 10% means the dB reduction is 20 dB because 20 log 10 = 20 dB.

A 2nd order low-pass filter will normally reduce the high frequencies at 40 dB per decade therefore, you need to have the filter's cut-off frequency half a decade below 100 Hz at 31.62 Hz (\$\sqrt{10\times 100}\$).

Here's an approximation: -

[image]

This was modelled with an RLC low pass filter [interactive tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html) having a butterworth response (\$\zeta\$ = 0.7071). Make sure that if you are using a sallen key filter the op-amp has a suitable GBWP or it might not meet your expectations.

Note that I didn't go to great lengths to choose LC to make exactly a cut-off 31.62 Hz but it's near enough to demonstrate that the marker at 100.66 Hz is 20 dB down.